# Change function to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is a statement used in my api. It is the second `$result` variable in the whole function below. How can one change it to use PDO?

```
$result = query("SELECT p.IdPhoto, p.device_token, /*title,*/ p.IdUser FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto='%d'", $IdPhoto) ;
```

Whole function

```
function stream($IdPhoto=0) {

if ($IdPhoto==0) {

   //Load Photos    
    $result = query("SELECT IdPhoto, device_token, /*title,*/ IdUser FROM photos /*p*/ ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 300 ");

} else {

    //Want this to be PDO :)
    $result = query("SELECT p.IdPhoto, p.device_token, /*title,*/ p.IdUser FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto='%d'", $IdPhoto) ;

}
```

Would this code work in the place of the second result variable? My goal is to change it to PDO so it can scale more successfully. SO far, no output yet.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pushchat', 'pushchat', 'A very secure password!!!');    
    $result = $dbh->query("SELECT p.IdPhoto, p.device_token, /*title,*/ p.IdUser FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto='%d'", $IdPhoto) ;
```

These are my database connection values

```
'host'     => 'localhost',
'dbname'   => 'pushchat',
'username' => 'pushchat',
'password' => 'A very secure password!!!',
```

**Update** php log file

```
[08-Apr-2016 03:39:25 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: IdPhoto in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Hi2/index.php on line 44
```

**Update**

Used the PDO syntax in a test file and the browser returned a row. How can I get the app to call it now via j son?

```
<?php  
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pushchat', 'pushchat', 'd]682\#%yI1nb3');

function new_function()

{
echo "hi<br>";

$an_int = 12;    

// If this is an integer

if (is_int($an_int)) 

{

global $conn;

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT IdPhoto, device_token, IdUser FROM photos ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 300 ");

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($result);

$swag_Bag = 'p.device_token';

    print_r($swag_Bag);

}

}
new_function();

 ?>
```

**Update**

This is how the app called the original `stream` function.

```
-(void)refreshStream
{
//The "stream" command from the web API
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"stream", @"command", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json)
{
    //got stream
    [self showStream:[json objectForKey:@"result"]];

    ...

    }];
}
```

Comment: The PDO documentation is very good, it has plenty of examples. Read it and you should understand how to use it.

Comment: It's a good habit to use prepared statements as it is better at protecting against sql injection.

Comment: @user5200287 thanks for your input. To use PDO, will I have to change the whole function, or just the variable I need?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'root', 'password');
function stream($IdPhoto=0) {
global $conn;

if ($IdPhoto==0) {

    // load the last 300 photos
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT IdPhoto, device_token, IdUser FROM photos ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 300 ");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} else {

//This is the statement i need to call explicitly via PDO

    //do the same as above, but just for the photo with the given id
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT p.IdPhoto, p.device_token, p.IdUser FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto= :idphoto ");
    $stmt->execute([':idphoto' => $IdPhoto]);
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}

if (!$stmt->errorInfo()[0]) {
    // if no error occured, print out the JSON data of the 
    // fetched photo data
    print json_encode($result);
} else {
    //there was an error, print out to the iPhone app
    errorJson('Photo stream is broken');
}
}
```

Comment: Nice work on converting that to a proper prepared statement. The new array notation makes doing this pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code @user5200287 I will definitely  use the syntax for the future. For now it doesn't get output for me though? Could it be because of the other methods in the file that I have and It needs to be put in exactly the right place?  I used this line of code for the connection `$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pushchat', 'pushchat', 'd]682\#%yI1nb3');`

Comment: try `var_dump($result);` to see if the queries are getting anything.

Comment: What could be going on? Additional info: there are other methods in the file (a total of 5) 4 of which don't use pdo. Should one still be able to call a method that uses pdo from a file considering there are other methods being used in the file that don't use pdo?  I'll keep at it. Update in progress.

Comment: that shouldn't be an issue. Did you get any results from the var_dump?

Comment: If this isn't working, I suspect a [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue. Try declaring `global $conn;` inside your `stream()` function.

Comment: @user5200287 I tried it and the browser didn't show results, just a blank page . I think it's because `$result` is  `$_POST` data. So far I've been gauging output from the app itself since the app calls the functions. This has happened before when I've tried var dump for post data being called via iOS app so I just use the app to gauge output.

Comment: That's a good point @DarwinvonCorax so I tried `global $conn;
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pushchat', 'pushchat', 'password');` but still no results in the app

Comment: @user3233623 No, it should be `function stream($IdPhoto=0) {
global $conn;` like @user5200287 's revised code shows. You need the `global` declaration *inside* the function to say that the variable was declared *outside* the function.

Comment: @br3nt stream currently isn't returning anything. I'm trying to get it work using pdo

Comment: In the other functions you use `query()` which is not a built in PHP function.

Comment: I made a github repo if you wanted to take a look. It has 2 files: one with the original stream function, and one with the updated PDO version. I also updated the question with the php_error.log output when I try to refresh the stream https://github.com/tonycrencren/API-files

Comment: I just realized that with the PDO syntax, the statements arent being called at all. The second I add the `$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'root', 'password');` line of code above the function declaration, the stream stops working. So @DarwinvonCorax you were right as I suspected. How can I get the file to read the line of code without crashing

Comment: Even if I leave the original function in place, it crashes the second I add this line ove code above the function `$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'root', 'password');`.

Comment: Thank you for the code @gommb have you any idea why this code works When I set it up in a test file but not when I call it in the app via j son? The original stream function worked via J son

Comment: Got it to work but only in a test file and not from the app yet. How can I call the function `stream` via the Afnetworking code that called it before. (Updated the question)

Comment: I have no experience in calling functions with JSON so I'm sorry to say I can't help you there.