# Change function to use PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This function is called `stream` and it is called via iOS app when the stream command is called. How can one change it to PDO?

```
function stream($IdPhoto=0) {

if ($IdPhoto==0) {

    $result = query("SELECT IdPhoto, device_token, /*title,*/ IdUser FROM photos /*p*/ ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 300 ");

} else {

    //do the same as above, but just for the photo with the given id
    $result = query("SELECT p.IdPhoto, p.device_token, /*title,*/ p.IdUser FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto='%d'", $IdPhoto) ;

}

if (!$result['error']) {
    // if no error occured, print out the JSON data of the 
    // fetched photo data
    print json_encode($result);

} else {
    //there was an error, print out to the iPhone app
    errorJson('Photo stream is broken');
}
}
```

Update. This is a method someone suggested [Change function to PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489196/change-function-to-pdo)

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'root',    'password');
function stream($IdPhoto=0) {
global $conn;

if ($IdPhoto==0) {

// load the last 300 photos
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT IdPhoto, device_token, IdUser FROM photos ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 300 ");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} else {

//This is the statement i need to call explicitly via PDO

//do the same as above, but just for the photo with the given id
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT p.IdPhoto, p.device_token, p.IdUser FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto= :idphoto ");
$stmt->execute([':idphoto' => $IdPhoto]);
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}

if (!$stmt->errorInfo()[0]) {
// if no error occured, print out the JSON data of the 
// fetched photo data
print json_encode($result);
} else {
//there was an error, print out to the iPhone app
errorJson('Photo stream is broken');
}
}
```

The thing is the stream only works with the first function. Can someone verify the syntax of the second PDO enabled function? Additional details: the iOS app calls the function using AFNetworking.